# Is there a libc in kernel space?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, glibc

Is there a libc in kernel space? I mean you have to build kernel against some libc right? So Is there a libc (probably statically-linked) sitting within kernel space?

If yes, how is this related to userland glibc? Must they be the same version?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19682782/relevance-of-libc-so-6-in-linux-kernel

Answer (score 13):

There is actually no libc in kernel space. Libc is user-space library, and you can't use it from kernel-space.

But almost all functions from libc that make sense in kernel space are ported. You can find headers in include/linux/ usually.

As far as I know these two implementations don't share codebase.

Answer (score 2):

Some of the functions that are available in `libc` are implemented inside the kernel code, for example there's a `printf` function that works as the normal (at least as far as the kernel code it self requires).

This means that while it looks like the code uses `libc` (by the functions that seem to be available) there actually no need to link it with a library (AFAIK).