# Relevance of libc.so.6 in Linux kernel

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, glibc

My question is whether Linux kernel contains `libc.so.6`? After googling and going through different links, we found that `libc.so.6`, is not a part of Linux kernel, as the kernel has same libraries implemented for its own use in kernel space. `libc.so.6` is a userspace library. But, still, the question was left, if the libc.so.6 is removed from "/lib", it crashes, as all the basic applications of Linux crashes.

So, the basic questions were left on:

1. Can Linux run without `libc.so.6`? If yes, where such implementation is used?
2. Who provides `libc.so.6`? Is it provided by Linux distributions only?
3. Does Linux internally supports threading or not?

Comment: this is not a programming question per say, this is more an architecture question

Comment: @bizzehdee: Probably, i dont think so, as Stack overflow isn't for only programming queries. It could be for conceptual questions, as here its for the relevance of glibc in linux

Comment: stackoverflow IS a programming question website... http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. you may want to try one of the other stackEXCHANGE websites such as http://askubuntu.com/ http://serverfault.com/ or http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19682782/relevance-of-libc-so-6-in-linux-kernel

Answer (score 7):

1. Yes. For example, I could write an application in assembly that did not use libc. Here are some examples: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/284797/hello-world-in-less-than-20-bytes
2. On Linux, glibc is a common implementation of libc: https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/
3. Yes. The threading options that glibc provides are a shim layer over a kernel interface.

Comment: But the point is, without glibc, Kernel will crash, and give a memory dump, and it will report that process init is not able to find the library files in specified path

Comment: Secondly, without glibc, i dont think that its practically useful to use Linux as an OS in any application. Then in that scenario a person can use firmware

Comment: @pRAShANT: Do you disagree that I can create applications without using libc?

Comment: @pRAShANT: In general, it's unlikely that many real world applications don't use a version of a libc. But that is because it enables developers to work faster, not because it's required. For example, libc lets me do printf. But I could rewrite printf myself using system calls to puts if I needed to.

Comment: Sorry, if my previous answers felt offensive, but my doubt was moreover to Relevance of libc. I know that its a user space library and its shouldn't be critical to not to use it. But, why did it crash and that makes me to put my inference, which is wrong i hope after above discussion that Linux can exist without libc

Comment: Actually, it was more about, if we say Linux OS, so is libc not indigenous to Linux

Comment: You're getting kernel space and userspace mixed up. The Linux *kernel* doesn't crash in the absence of a libc, it is the userspace software that was compiled to dynamically load libc on execution that crashes (or rather, not load) - since they need libc to operate.

Answer (score 3):

> Can Linux run without libc.so.6? If yes, where is this the case?

Compiling the code with option `-nostdlib` won't use standard libraries,

man [GCC](http://linux.die.net/man/1/gcc) tells,

> -nostdlib
>       Do not use the standard system startup files or libraries when linking. No 
>       startup files and only the libraries you specify will be passed to the linker. 
>       The compiler may generate calls to memcmp, memset, memcpy and memmove. These 
>       entries are usually resolved by entries in libc. These entry points should be 
>       supplied through some other mechanism when this option is specified.

Check [webpage](https://blogs.oracle.com/ksplice/entry/hello_from_a_libc_free) for good glibc free implementation.

Comment: Then in this case it will not require glibc to run applications, and on booting Linux in this case, it will not crash? Will it proceed for the normal login and shell prompt?

Comment: @pRAShANT: "Will it proceed for the normal login and shell prompt?" Probably not, because the shell is a userspace program, and most shell implementations (like most other userspace programs) use libc. When the shell starts, it tries to load libc. When that fails, the shell crashes. But the kernel doesn't crash. The shell is not a part of the kernel - the shell is a userspace program.